# Rails 3.2 and getting AR to properly order this query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I currently have a scope where I am attempting to find last record created in an association and select it if a particular boolean value is false

IE Foo has_many Bar's and Bar's has a boolean column named bazzed

```
scope :no_baz,   joins(:bars).order("bars.id DESC").limit(1).where("bars.bazzed = 'f'")
```

The problem with this is that rails turns this query into something like this

```
SELECT "foos".* FROM "foos" INNER JOIN "bars" ON "bars"."foo_id" = "foos"."id" WHERE (bars.bazzed = 'f') ORDER BY bars.id DESC LIMIT 1
```

the problem lies that rails is calling the order and limit after the where clause, what i'm looking for is to do the order and limit first to try  and find the last bar that has bazzed set to false.

Is there a native AR way to perform the query I am attempting to accomplish?

EDIT

I am trying to grab the foo's that have a bar  where the last bar they have has bazzed set to false and only if the last bar that that foo has has a false bazzed.

Comment: What if you try the following: "scope :no_baz,   joins(:bars).order("bars.id DESC").where("bars.bazzed = 'f'").first". As I'm not sure if it works, I don't propose it as an answer. ^^

Comment: trying to grab the first record only if the bazzed field is false. This at the moment grabs the first bazzed regardless if its the first record or not.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I would suggest this for the query on the "foo" model:

```
Foo.bars.where("bars.bazzed = ?", 'f').all( :order => "created_at DESC").first
```

Note: 'f' can be replaced by false, depending on the value you use in your "bazzed" column, of course.

[Edit]

Ok, as I think I better understand the problem, here is a suggestion, but for a public method and not a scoped query.

```
def no_baz
  all_no_baz_foos = Array.new
  Foo.all.each do |foo|
      last_bar = foo.bars.all.order("bars.id DESC").first
      if last_bar.bazzed == 'f'
        all_no_baz_foos << foo
      end
  end
  return all_no_baz_foos
end
```

This method will return an Array with all the no_baz_foos record in it. As I did not test my code, you may have to change few things for it to work, but I think you get the idea.

For the "scope" method, I just can't find a way to chain correctly the queries to have the desired result. If anyone else knows how to achieve that using a scope, I'll be glad to hear the solution too.

Comment: Wouldn't that return the last created bar with bazzed is set to false? What I am trying to accomplish is to go through all of a foos validations and to pick out the foo's that have the last created bar with the bazzed value is false. So if foo's last bars.bazzed is 't' I do not want to return that foo.

Comment: Oh... I did not understand that, sorry... Hmm, what is the relation between bar and foo? Cause, you have "foo has_many bars" but does "bar has_many foos" or "bar has_one foo" or...? Would be more understandable if you'd use a more concrete example like "users has many posts with the column published" or something like that. ^^

Comment: This is a tough problem, does the scope method really important? Because, maybe, it would be better and easier to create a method, I'll edit my post with a suggestion.

Comment: Doing so as a method definitely can get the task done and I do appreciate the help so far thanks! Still trying to do this in a scope  for now though if its possible

Comment: I thought about something else, maybe you can try to chain scopes? Like: scope :last_bar, joins(:bars).order("bars.id DESC").limit(1). And then another scope: scope :no_baz, last_bar.and(self.bars.bazzed != 'f'). Not sure if its better, but it is definitely something to try, cause you do are chaining two different scopes in fact. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using a class method for now but the problem with that lies that it returns an array object and not an active record relation which is what i'm trying to return.  Still attempting to get the query correctly done.

Comment: thie SQL still isn't working quite right  (getting syntax errors now)  trying to do something like   scope :test, find_by_sql("SELECT foos.* FROM foos INNER JOIN bars ON bars.foos = foos.id ORDER BY bars.id DESC LIMIT 1 WHERE (bars.bazzed = 'f'))") syntax error right where the WHERE  is .. Essentially I want something like that but  with the working where clause at the end